# What windows forms control best matches a Selectable list

Tags: c#, winforms

I want a box that shows 5 items (of the 20 that are available).  The other fifteen are scroll-able to.

When I click on one of the items, it acts like a combo box in that it is the one selected/highlighted.

Is there a control for doing this already?

I have tried using the combobox and setting the height on it, but the height is still only one row high.

```
ComboBox cboResults;
cboResults = new ComboBox();
cboResults.Height = 500;
cboResults.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
cboResults.IntegralHeight = true;

frmLookup.Controls.Add(cboResults);
```

Am I using the wrong control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [ListBox](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0460__GUI-Windows-Forms/AddItemstoListBox.htm), setting a default height you can achieve the scrollable behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

A `ComboBox` is a **combination** of an editable field with a list. The list either drops down or is shown and scrollable. For this set the `DropDownStyle=Simple`!

However a simple `ListBox` is probably more suitable, unless you do want to allow the user to enter data.

Of, if you want to display more complex data, maybe with columns a `ListView` is best; I found I promote most `ListBoxes` sooner or later to `ListViews`..